# Get latitude and longitude from Wikipedia page via API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I wanted to use the following API and pss in different suburbs to get the latitude and longitude of the suburb or address.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Also, the list of suburbs is going to be around 16,000 so how do I extract geocordinates using this API?

Comment: Please improve the question, it is unclear what you would like to do. Focus on what you want to achieve, not how you think you could achieve it.

Comment: I want to get lat long of suburbs in a country using the wikipedia api.Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [GeoData API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#API) or for the equivalent [Wikidata queries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API#wbgetclaims) for [P625](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P625).

Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=coordinates&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Suburbs_in_the_United_Kingdom

```
{
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "1249195": {
                "pageid": 1249195,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Cassiobury",
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "lat": 51.66,
                        "lon": -0.401,
                        "primary": "",
                        "globe": "earth"
                    }
                ]
            },
...
```